# Network state with mvvmcross?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, network-state

I use mvvmcross to develop application which target WPF, IOS and android platforms.

How can I get network state and globally network informations ?
Ex : IP address, network interface (Ethernet, Wifi, 3g, ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For mvvmcross v3, there is a Network plugin which provides information on network connectivity - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Network

However, this is only implemented for iOS/Touch currently - it's there just in order to satisfy Apple's `Reachability` requirements.

In order to provide this across multiple platforms, you will need to add and implement your own interfaces - either extending this plugin, creating a new plugin or just using IoC injection from the UI projects.

I'm not aware of anyone who has done this already, but I'd love to see this contributed back to open source.